# Vmware and Virtualbox issues with iphone device

Tags: iphone, xcode, virtualbox, vmware

Yo,

Anyone here use a VM (VirtualBox or VMware) and code on MacOS Catalina 10.15.x or Big Sur as guest ? Personally, I can't connect my iphone to xcode 11 and 12 (Iphone 5S: ios 14.4).

I tried multiple fix from the forum, as change the vmx file (skip-reset, skip-refresh, skip-setconfig" with the right pid and vid), set USB device to 2.0 (in VMware and VirtualBox), upgrade the IOS,  but nothing was successful for now. However, the iphone is recognized and listed in the System information but nowhere else.

Somebody here have the same config and can use his iphone ? Had you do something in particular ?

Edit: The host is Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution i found is to install "Catalina" and only Catalina, on VMware (with usb 2.0 of course). Don't use virtual box. Don't upgrade to big sur on Vmware lol. peace